# How to visualize a vector field on a parametrized surface?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, graphics3d, visualization

I'm solving a differential equation by NDSolve. After solving the equation, I got the solution for $$. But, now I want to visualise the vector(which makes an angle phi with the normal) on the parametric surface(catenoid in this case).

Here is my code (ELE is my differential equation):

```
s = NDSolve[{ELE==0, f[vin]== 0.0, f[vf] == 1.57}, f, 
{v,vin,vf}]
data = Table[Flatten[{v, Evaluate[{f[v]} /. s]}], {v, vin, vf, 
0.1}];
```

I can visualize the surface normal using the following code:

```
s[u_, v_] := {e1*Cosh[v/e1]*Cos[u],  e1*Cosh[v/e1]*Sin[u] , v}
UnitNormalVector[f_, {u_, u0_}, {v_, v0_}] := Block[{f0, g0},
             f0 = f /. {u -> u0, v -> v0};
             g0 = Transpose[D[f, {{u, v}}] /. {u -> u0, v -> v0}];
             Arrow[{f0, f0 + Normalize[Cross @@ g0]}]]

Show[ParametricPlot3D[s[u, v], {u, 0, 2*Pi}, {v, -10, 10},
      Mesh -> True, PlotPoints -> 100], Graphics3D[
      Table[UnitNormalVector[s[u, v], {u, u0}, {v, v0}], 
      {u0, 0,2*Pi, 0.5}, {v0, -10, 10, 2}]],PlotRange -> All]
% /. Arrow[stuff__] -> {Blue, Arrow[Tube[stuff, 0.7]]}
```

Here, $s[u,v]$ is the parametrised surface. I tried to plot the vector by making an interpolation function and using it in place of **UnitNormalVector**, in the above code. But that does not work.

Is there any way I can visualise the solution on a parametrized surface? I'm looking a way to visualise a function which can be created from the solution of NDSolve.

P.S. - The solution has u-symmetry. It only varies along v-direction i.e. in the z-direction.

Comment: Have you seen [`SliceVectorPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SliceVectorPlot3D.html)? If you specify the surface using [`ParametricRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricRegion.html), you should be able to get what you want.

Comment: @LukasLang For SliceVectorPlot3D, I need to use Cartesian  coordinates. I didn't find any way to plot using  SliceVectorPlot3D.

Comment: @Aru can you use something like [`FromPolarCoordinates`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FromPolarCoordinates.html) to perform the transformation?